# Dereferencing int pointer address to structure

Tags: c++, pointers

How do you make `ai` have the actual size of the structure that `mptr` is pointing to? In this case `ai` is returning size of the `Object` pointer which is 4 bytes. I am trying to get the actual structure size of the `Object` pointed by `mptr`

```
#include <iostream>    
using namespace std;

struct Object {
    int t;
    int g;
    float gBuffer;
};

int CreateObject() {
    Object* obj = new Object;
    return (unsigned int)obj;
}


int main() {
    unsigned int mptr = CreateObject();
    size_t ai = sizeof((Object*)mptr);

    cout << "Hello World" << endl; 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Never ever cast a pointer to an `int`! Or to an `unsigned int` that is then implicitly casted to an `int`...

Use `uintptr_t` if you have to do something like this, but in this case there is no reason to do it at all. Just return an `Object*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either "use the object itself" to get the size (note this all happens at compile time, so the compiler basically looks the type up for you).

```
Object* obj;
size_t size = sizeof(*obj);
```

Or use the type directly:

```
size_t size = sizeof(Object);
```

Advantage of the first way is that you can change the type of `obj` without having to search for every single `sizeof` you did on that variable through your whole codebase.

Full code, removing the cast to `int`:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


struct Object{
  int t;
  int g;
  float gBuffer;
};

Object* CreateObject(){
    return new Object;
}


int main(){
    Object* mptr = CreateObject();
    size_t ai = sizeof(*mptr); // or sizeof(Object)

    cout << "Hello World" << endl; 
    return 0;
}
```

---

**Update:**

It gets a bit more complicated once you try to get the size of a C++ standard library container.

Think about those containers like this:

```
struct container {
    size_t dataLength;
    char*  ptrToData;
};
```

As you already learned, the size of a pointer to an object is not equal to the size of the object itself.

```
sizeof(char*) -> 4 (32bit) or 8 (64bit) bytes
sizeof(char)  -> 1 byte
```

Likewise, the size of a container isn't the same as the size of the data it manages.
An instance `c` of the container from above could point to a 1024 byte large `char` array, but `sizeof(c)` would still return 8 (on 32bit systems).

```
// Note that this is not 100% correct because of the padding
// the compiler could add to the struct, but this is out of the
// scope of this answer.
container c;
sizeof(c);                      // resolves to
sizeof(size_t) + sizeof(char*); // resolves to
4              + 4;             // 32bit
```

The size of the data pointed to by `ptrToData` would be stored in `dataLength`, so we could get the size by simply looking at the container.

**Note that this totally differs from sizeof()**

`sizeof()` returns the size of an object that is known **at compile time**.
The C++ standard library containers are managing dynamic memory, which means there is no way the compiler (and hence `sizeof()`) can know how much memory you will allocate through the container at run time.

Most of the time there is no reason to know about the size of a container itself (actually if you think you need to know it, you are probably doing something wrong).

What you really need to know about, e.g., an `std::vector` is the number of elements it currently holds. For an `std::vector` you would get the number elements the container has *allocated memory* for by calling the [`std::vector<>::capacity()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/capacity) method and the actual number of elements currently in the container by calling [`std::vector<>::size()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/size).

Confused? Read about vectors [here](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/stl/article.php/c4027/C-Tutorial-A-Beginners-Guide-to-stdvector-Part-1.htm) or just google it.

Comment: But it's so much more fun to explain sizeof multiplication (e.g. `(sizeof*obj)`)

Comment: I love this joke since I heard it the first time.

Comment: what about if Object structure contains a vector?

Comment: sizeof(std::vector<T>) would give you the size of the container itself, not of the array it points to. I will add handling of the standard containers to my answer.